# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.substring(int, int)

Tags: android

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.substring(int, int)
Fatal Exception main

Comment: please add your code

Comment: @SamiKanafani this is not necessary, it is a duplicate anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown when you are trying to use the substring method on a null string, try checking the value of the string you are invoking the substring method.
If you want to avoid the crash you can use the following code

```
if(str!=null){
   //where the str is the string you are invoking the method on
   substr = str.substring(7, 17);
}
```

Comment: Since this is more often than not a programming error, the crash is preferable over some strange misbehaviour due to substr not being set. (Fail fast).